# Hadamard's product of Fibonacci generating functions.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

$F(s) = \frac{1}{1-s-s^2}=\sum_{n\geq0}F_ns^n$.
I want to calculate $F(s) \circ F(s) = \sum_{n\geq0}F_{n}^2s^n$.
I have tried using Binet"s formula, but problem remains unsolved.

Comment: Isn't it the definition of Hadamard product of the series $\sum a_ns^n$ and $\sum b_ns^n$, the series $\sum a_nb_ns^n$? Then the formula you need to prove is a direct application of the definition of Hadamard's product of generating functions.

Comment: Yes it is. But what formula do u mean?
I want express $F(s) \circ F(s)$ as rational function.

Comment: I see now what you want. "calculate" is too ambiguous, so I understood you only wanted to calculate $F(s)\circ F(s)$, i.e. to show that $F(s)\circ F(s)=\sum F_n^2 s^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square the Binet formula to get $$F_n^2=\frac{\phi^{2n}-2(-1)^n+\phi^{-2n}}{5},$$where $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$. Now the series splits into three geometric series, where the common ratios are respectively $\phi^2s$, $-s$, and  $\phi^{-2}s$.